# TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer. Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я новичок в программировании. Решил написать алгоритм сортировки выбором:

```
def findSmallest(arr):
    smallest = arr[0]
    smallest_index = 0
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        if arr[i] < smallest:
            smallest = arr[i]
            smallest_index = i
        return smallest_index

def selectionSort(arr):
    newArr = []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        smallest = findSmallest(arr)
        newArr.append(arr.pop(smallest))
    return newArr

a = [5, 3, 6, 2, 10]
print(selectionSort(a))
```

Выдало такую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sort_by_selection.py", line 19, in <module>
    print(selectionSort(a))
  File "sort_by_selection.py", line 14, in selectionSort
    newArr.append(arr.pop(smallest))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Почему возникает эта ошибка и как ее исправить?

Comment: сдвиньте return на уровень for в findSmallest

Comment: кстати, можно и без этой функции - `newArr.append(arr.pop(arr.index(min(arr))))`

Comment: splash58, а можно вообще без программы) - `sorted(arr)`

Понятно же, что задача методическая, а не практическая)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Почему TypeError:** на последнем проходе цикла в `selectionSort()` у вас уже `len(arr)` всегда будет равен единице (это компилятор в голове, на практике не проверял). Таким образом, функция `findSmallest()` ничего не вернет, так как итератор `range(1,1)` является пустым и из-за этого в цикл `for i in range(1, len(arr))` мы просто не зайдем. Без ключевого слова **return** функция возвращает **None**, а дальше вы пытаетесь выполнить `arr.pop(None)`, что и вызывает эту ошибку.

```py
>>> [1].pop()
1
>>> [1].pop(None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    [1].pop(None)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

**Решение:** проверяйте условие длины массива меньше двух.

**Также** вынесите `return smallest_index` за тело цикла. Тут вы просто ошиблись и иначе результат будет неверный.